# remove the class to an item

Tags: jquery, removeclass

Hi I need to remove the class 'fancy' to all fancy items,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fancy').removeClass('.fancy');
    alert($('.fancy').length + 'comentarios');
});
</script>
```

Trying like that, the class is not removed and the alert shows me '6comentarios' so there are 6 items selected,

what am i missing??

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to provide a selector as an argument, simply a class name.

Try:

`$('.fancy').removeClass('fancy');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.fancy').removeClass('fancy');
```

will work. Dot before className means "class", so in this case (removeClass) it's not allowed/required

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/efbb8/2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `fancy` instead of `.fancy` inside of `removeClass()`

Answer (score -1):

You are removing the class from an array of objects. That will probably not work. Try the [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
$('.fancy').each( function() { this.removeClass('fancy'); } );
```

Comment: Oh yeah, and according to the other answers: Use "fancy" instead of ".fancy" in the removeClass function.